# Unable to compile mysql-proxy into an rpm

Tags: mysql, lua, mysql-proxy

I am trying to compile and package mysql-proxy-0.8.4.tar.gz into rpm. I followed the instructions to build

```
[root@localhost mysql-proxy]# rpmbuild -ta --clean mysql-proxy-0.8.4.tar.gz
```

I get this error

```
checking which pkg-config file to use to find Lua... configure: error: MySQL Proxy can't be built using --without-lua, lua 5.1 is required
error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.r6iTWn (%build)


RPM build errors:
Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.r6iTWn (%build)
```

I checked my build machine and I have all the build dependencies, I can see that pkg-config listing lua libraries

```
[root@localhost mysql-proxy]# pkg-config --list-all | less
lua                        Lua - An Extensible Extension Language
```

Could someone let me know what am I missing?

Comment: Try `apt-get install liblua5.1-0-dev`

Comment: @hjpotter92 Not a very helpful suggestion for an rpm based system.

Answer (score 0):

That error is telling you that you might need to pass `--with-lua` to rpmbuild when you build the package.

You also, as @hjpotter92 was getting at, likely need to install the `lua-devel` package to go along with the `lua` package.

Try installing that first and then re-running your command and see if the error changes.

Comment: my build machine has lua-devel install installed. Could you let me know how to pass "--with-lua" to rpm build

Comment: @skokal01 Exactly like that. Just include it on the `rpmbuild` command line. Though I would have expected it to default on as it is necessary.

Comment: [root@localhost mysql-proxy]# rpmbuild -ta --clean mysql-proxy-0.8.4.tar.gz --with-lua
--with-lua: unknown option
I get this error

Comment: Hm... looks like `--with=lua` is the way to do that. Sorry.